# Enrolled in AD realm, but can´t resolve AD users with getent passwd

Tags: 14.04, active-directory

Situation:
Windows SBS Server (AD controller, DNS server), Proxmox 4.1 server hosting a Ubuntu 14.04 lxc container.

What I want to achieve:
Integrate the Ubuntu container into the AD, so that I´m able to log in with AD credentials.

What I did:
I followed this guide:

http://koo.fi/blog/2015/06/16/ubuntu-14-04-active-directory-authentication/?replytocom=3415#respond

This worked fine for me the first time, except I had to edit the nsswitch.conf. Then I had to shut down both physical servers to install new fans and clean them. After rebooting them I can´t login with any AD user in Ubuntua anymore, resolving them using getent doesn´t return anything.

I´ve set up multiple new containers (with a new IP and a different name of course) and followed the guide again. I can enroll in the realm, but I still can´t resolve the AD users.

The configuration is exactly the same in all containers.

Any tipps for me? Any logs I can provide?
Thanks in advance.

Edit (160421):
Following the above steps with a Ubuntu 14.04 KVM machine works. I can resolve users using getent, I can su AD-user, I can log in over ssh with AD users.

All containers that have been enrolled in the AD realm appear in the AD management console on the windows server in the desired ou.

---

Here´s the configuration:

krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = MY.DOMAIN

    krb4_config = /etc/krb.conf
    krb4_realms = /etc/krb.realms
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true


    v4_instance_resolve = false
    v4_name_convert = {
            host = {
                    rcmd = host
                    ftp = ftp
            }
            plain = {
                    something = something-else
            }
    }
    fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

[realms]
    MY.DOMAIN= {
    kcd = domain-server
    admin_server = domain-server
    default_domain = my.domain
    }
[domain_realm]
     .my.domain= MY.DOMAIN
      my.domain= MY.DOMAIN

[login]
    krb4_convert = true
    krb4_get_tickets = false
```

realmd.conf:

```
[service]
automatic-install = no

[users]
default-home = /home/%D/%U
default-shell = /bin/bash

[c4b.local]
computer-ou = OU=Linux_2,DC=my,DC=domain
automatic-id-mapping = yes
fully-qualified-names = no
```

nsswitch.conf:

```
passwd:         compat sss
group:          compat sss
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
netgroup:       nis sss
sudoers:        files sss
```

Running realm list returns:

```
my.domain
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: MY.DOMAIN
  domain-name: my.domain
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-tools
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: libnss-sss
  required-package: libpam-sss
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-bin
  login-formats: %U
  login-policy: allow-realm-logins
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there were two problems:

1) I installed ntp and set the windows server as the only timesource, but forgot to set the timezone.

2) The permissions for /etc/sssd/sssd.conf were wrong. The file needs to be owned by root.root and needs to have 0600 permissions.

Now I am able to resolve AD-users and groups and I can log in with AD-users. Only su AD-user doesn´t work, but this is irrelevant for my setup.